# Reload tableview based on segments options

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I'm trying to change the table data when the user changes the control segments. But right now my code crashes. Here is how I set up the segments:

```
  let w = view.frame.width
  let s = PinterestSegment(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 117, width: w - 40, height: 40), titles: ["Our faviorte", "Restuarnt", "Coffee", "Pharmacy", "Supermarketr", "Home", "Wemoent' Style", "Man's Style", "Beauty", "Travel"])
        s.style.titleFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: UIFont.Weight(rawValue: 5))
        view.addSubview(s)
```

TableView data is saved from api and filtered based on the segments options.

```
 var info = Shops(shopname: shopName, Logo: logoString, family_id: familiy_id , design : designImage , rate : rate, time : time )
                        self.shops.append(info)
                  // filters all the segments this way
                        self.coffee = self.shops.filter { $0.shopname == "Starbucks" }
```

Now when the segments is changed in ViewdidLoad :

```
 s.valueChange = { index in
    if index == 1 {

        print(self.coffee)// it prints the data correctly 
        self.shops = self.coffee
    }

    if index == 2 {
        self.shops = self.Restuarnt

    }
    if index == 3 {
        self.shops = self.Pharmacy

    }
 self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

I get an `fatal error: Index out of range`

DataSource and Delegate :

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if searchActive {
            return auxiliar!.count
        }else{
            return   allShops.count

        }
    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if searchActive

        {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ShopTableViewCell
            let entry1 = auxiliar?[indexPath.row]
            cell.shopImage.hnk_setImage(from: URL(string: (entry1?.Logo)!))
            cell.shopName.text = entry1?.shopname
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1 , alpha : 0.5)
            cell.time.text = entry1?.time
            cell.star.rating = Double((entry1?.rate)!)
            return cell
        }
        else {

            let shop = allShops[indexPath.row]

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ShopTableViewCell

            let entry = shops[indexPath.row]

            cell.shopImage.hnk_setImage(from: URL(string: entry.Logo))
            cell.shopName.text = entry.shopname
            cell.star.rating = Double(entry.rate)
            cell.time.text = entry.time
           cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1 , alpha : 0.5)
            return cell

        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please add tableview datasource methods here to check the tableview datasource implementation?

Comment: Just updated my question can you check please

Comment: please check my answer

Comment: how to set particular index when PinterestSegment loads first time @leo0019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method should be like this,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if searchActive {
            return auxiliar!.count
        }else{
            return   self.shops.count

        }
    }
```

Because every time you setting self.shops on segment change

You can save selected segment index in some variable which is defined globally for class and access that in cellForRow index method

And I think you can comment this line because this your not using any where in cellForRow index method

let shop = allShops[indexPath.row]

Comment: then I should add `var isCoffee = false` and `var isFood = false`and `var isPharmacy = false` under index callback then in `numberOfRowsInSection` I have to check if it's coffee segments or ...

Comment: no just define one variable which saves selected index in that and you can use that for checking condition

Comment: No need to take extra variable to save "selected segment index", Use selectedSegmentIndex property to retrieve currently selected index.

Comment: `var selectedIndex = ""` then in `numberOfRowsInSection` if  selectedIndex ==1 then fetch coffee and if 2 fetch pharamcy ...

Comment: yes that's also possible if you have defined segment at class level not in method scop

Comment: @leo0019 instead of checking condition you can direct return this self.shops.count because ulimately you setting this array

Comment: I didn't get your answer can you explain more please

Comment: @leo0019 you are setting  this array self.shops while setting selected index on changing of segment selection so you can directly return this array's count instead of allShops.count, ........So Replace allShops.count with self.shops.count and comment this line "let shop = allShops[indexPath.row]"

Comment: @leo0019 if your problem is solved please accept my answer

Answer (score 1):

Check your UITableView's delegate and Data Sources: `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. You have data for tableView's cell index in your data-source (`self.Restuarnt`, `self.Pharmacy`).

Comment: Is there any other way to do this because I set up the segments in ViewdidLoud. I cant access index of segments from `cellForRowAt`. Check my question I just updated it

Answer (score 1):

Find the crash point by logging in console first, It may be crashing from tableview datasource method. Make sure self.Restuarnt and self.Pharmacy are printing data well. One more thing is, you have used **multiple If statements** ! instead use **if-else-if Ladder**, because once index is matched, there is no sense for checking for other indexes ! !

Comment: Is there any other way to do this because I set up the segments in ViewdidLoud. I cant access index of segments from cellForRowAt. Check my question I just updated it

Comment: You can access selected index or title at anytime till segment object is not deallocated. Use segment.titleForSegmentAtIndex(segment.selectedSegmentIndex) to access selected segment's string.

Comment: I set up the segment in ViewdidLoud

Comment: you can always access selected index anytime irrespective of setup of object.

Answer (score 0):

You might be making a mistake in number of rows. You need to relaod tableview whenever segment changes.